# Is it possible to do a "if-ever" in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Okay I'm not sure what the official name for what I want is so I will refer to it as an "if-ever" function.

Basically I want to say if a certain cell is equal to a certain value at any point then another designated cell will return a certain value if the original cell is change the designated cell will still return the same value.

An example to make this clear:

Let cell A1 be =randbetween(0,10) now refreshing the formulas will return a random integer from {0,1,2,...,10}.

Now I want to say if A1 is ever equal to 5 for instance then cell A2 will return the value 5 (or any other number/words) and will be fixed, i.e. should we then in the future change A1, A2 will still remain with the value 5 (or whatever else we used).

Hopefully this is clear what I want.

Is this even possible and how would I achieve something like this in excel?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: That sounds easy to do with Excel rules. Do your research. I think this post is not so appropriate for StackOverflow. This [site](https://superuser.com/) will be best for your questions.

Comment: Okay how would I go about it then?

Answer (score 0):

Just with plain excel the answer is **NO**. 
The formulas will recalculate every time. However, with [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) it is possible.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and give it a try. You need to explore the `Worksheet_Change` event and to make sure that it checks a specific target for the value. Then simply change the target and that's it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel

Comment: How could I adapt this so I can do it with my rand number example? (I am inexperienced with VBA unfortunately)

Comment: @Tom - read the examples in the documentation & try them. `Target` in the documentation is the range, that is changed. Once it gets a given value (from the random function), then exit the function earlier. But in general, spend a few hours reading online tutorials for VBA before trying.